# Rendered sum is displaying as NaN

Tags: reactjs, arrays, sum, render

I am trying to total  a column of numbers by className and have that total displayed. However the result is NaN, and I am not sure where I need to make changes.

Here is the code I currently have that takes hoursCompleted (these are the ones displayed) and I am trying to create a "total" row at the bottom of this with output displaying the totalHoursCompleted.

```
let hoursCompleted = document.getElementsByClassName('data-legend-info-part');

let totalHoursCompleted = [];

for (let i = 0; i < hoursCompleted.length; i++) {
const hours = hoursCompleted[i];
totalHoursCompleted.push(Number(hours));
}

let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < totalHoursCompleted.length; i++) {
sum += totalHoursCompleted[i];
}
```

Here is what I have set up for return, and with that the NaN.

```
return (
<div className="pie-chart-wrapper">
<div id={`pie-chart-container-${pieChartId}`} className="pie-chart" />
<div>
<div className="pie-chart-legend-header">
<div>Name</div>
<div>{dataLegendHeader}</div>
</div>
{/*Values for Name Header entered here*/}
{Object.keys(dataLegend).map(key => (
<div key={key} className="pie-chart-legend-item">
<div className="data-legend-color" style={{ backgroundColor: color(key) 
}} />
<div className="data-legend-info">
{dataLegend[key].map(legendPart => (
<div className="data-legend-info-part">{legendPart}</div>
))}
</div>
</div>
 ))}
{/*Values for Hours Header entered here*/}

<div className="pie-chart-legend-item">
<div className="data-legend-info">
Total Hours Worked:
<div className="data-legend-info-part">{sum}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
);
```

So if there's 3 tasks, all with 4 hoursCompleted. I want the {sum} to display 12. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: hoursCompleted is an dom object element that you are getting. it is not 3 tasks or anything. you have not  defined in your html where the 3 tasks are. once you define that html tags. you need to fetch those tasks elements and then add up the sum from each element. currently you are taking "data-legend-info-part" dom element and trying to loop on it and sum it.

Comment: Sorry, I did a poor job explaining. There is far more code than what I showed. The 3 tasks are entered under two classes, one is the title of the task(className is Data-Legend-Info), and the hours worked on that class are entered under className Data-Legend-Info-Part. So what I showed above is trying to take the values entered into Data-Legend-Info-Part, sum them, and then display that sum

Comment: Why is this tagged Reactjs? `getElementsByClassName` should not be used in React context/

Comment: Is there an alternative method, React based, that allows me to get obtain info from a specific class? Majority of this code is not mine so I'm doing my best to adapt and evolve with it